# PHP не генерирует ошибки при обращении к элементам массива у не массива

Tags: php

Странное дело. Всю жизнь считал, что подобный код должен выдавать хотя бы Notice в PHP. А по факту ничего (PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3), даже с включенным E_STRICT (либо у меня PHP собран криво).

```
$data = null;
if ($data[0]['asdsad'] == null) {
    echo "case 1\n";
} else {
    echo "case 2\n";
}
```

В результате скрипт выводит "case 1" и больше ничего. Аналогично при $data = false, integer, string. Ошибки появляются только если $data вообще не определена или если $data = [].

Аналогично я полагал, что неявное определение массива через $data[] = 'asd', когда $data не определена, тоже должно генерировать предупреждение, хотя бы в E_STRICT, но тоже ничего.

Это нормально вообще? В всех так? Есть идеи почему так?

Answer (score 1):

При [преобразовании в массив](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) строки, дробного, целого, булева, ресурса – получается массив с единственным нулевым элементом, содержащим это значение.

Обращение к строке как к массиву - с квадратными скобками - дает N-й символ этой строки: `$s = 'abcd'; $s[3] === 'd'`.

Обращение таким же образом к числу вроде бы, не документировано:

```
$data = 5;
var_dump( (array)$data); /* array(1) {
    [0]=> int(5)
  } */

var_dump( $data[0]); // Null - не понятно, почему
```

В вашем случае дважды происходит обращение к Null как к массиву: `$data = NULL; $data[0] === NULL; $data[0]['anykey'] === NULL;` Поэтому ошибкам взяться неоткуда.

Что касается `$data[] = 'asd'` — это короткий вариант записи `array_push()`, но есть разница. Про это пишут в [доке](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> Note: array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not
> an array. This differs from the $var[]
> behaviour where a new array is created.

Т.е. просто создается новый массив в таком варианте. Поэтому тоже нет ошибок.

Comment: Так здесь нет конверсии типов. Я же не пишу нигде "(array) $data", я просто обращаюсь к $data как к массиву, и если это не массив, то результат должен быть аналогичен тому, как если я обращаюсь к несуществующему элементу массива. Но почему-то когда я обращаюсь к несуществующему элементу массива есть Notice, а когда обращаюсь вообще не к массиву, то нет ничего.

Comment: Вот пример, доказывающий, что здесь нет конверсии типов:

    $data = 5;
    if ($data[0] == 5) {
        echo "Конверсия есть\n";
    } else {
        echo "Конверсии нет\n";
    }

Если бы здесь была конверсия, то 5 преобразовалось бы в array(5) и условие бы выполнилось. Но оно не выполняется.

Comment: Если же добавить перед условием строчку

    $data = (array) $data;

То тогда условие выполняется. Следовательно, ваш ответ неверен.

Comment: действительно, `$data = 5; var_dump( $data[0]); // Null`

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: > var_dump( $data[0]); // Null - не понятно, почему

Понятно почему. Как я уже говорил, здесь нет конверсии типов. Здесь идёт обращение к нулевому элементу массива (ну или символу, если строка). Но у integer нет элементов, поэтому обращение к элементу должно генерировать предупреждение, а результат выражения должен быть null. Всё так и происходит, за исключением предупреждения. Его почему-то нет, как будто всё в полном порядке.

Comment: Про $data[] = 'asd' понятно. Спасибо за ссылку на документацию. Но я всё равно считаю, что такой способ записи (без явной инициализации) должен быть deprecated.

Comment: > В вашем случае дважды происходит обращение к Null как к массиву: $data = NULL; $data[0] === NULL; $data[0]['anykey'] === NULL; Поэтому ошибкам взяться неоткуда.

Как это неоткуда? Мы производим операцию, которая для этого типа не применима. Не должен ли PHP хотя бы намекнуть нам об этом? Я ведь не говорю о том, что результат выражения должен быть другим, а лишь о том, что PHP должен бы ругаться на это. Хотя бы PHP-Notice.

Comment: Ну так поднять знамёна, конницу, и на [...](https://bugs.php.net/report.php) оформлять отношения, не? : )